# AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'destroy' could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, destroy

I'm having some trouble with my rails application. I checked other questions of this error and none of them are applicable to my application.

I need to destroy a row, and to do that I direct a form to the action 'destroy' within my controller.

Here is where I direct it.

```
<%= form_for(:pallet_hist, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => params[:id]}) do |f| %>
```

Here's the action within the controller.

```
class PalletHistController < ApplicationController

def destroy
    @pallet_hist = PalletHist.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Entry '#{pallet_hist.id}' deleted successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index', :id => @pallet_hist.pallet_id)
  end
end
```

I can't figure out why it's still giving me this error.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post] 

  root 'pallets#index'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a destroy action, you want to use the `delete` HTTP method within your routes. So for a custom route (if you're not using `resources` to generate a set of routes) it would be something like:

`delete 'my_url', to: 'mycontroller#my_delete_action'`

If you were to use `resources` it would give you index, show, new, create, edit, update, and destroy routes.

Also, I'd be surprised if your `:url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => params[:id]}` works. The `url:` option *should* contain the destroy action's url. So if you did that custom route I mentioned above, the url would be something closer to `mycontroller_path` and then there should be a `method: :delete` after it. I could be wrong on this last part, but thought I'd give the extra information in case I'm right.

EDIT:

If all you need is a delete button, then you probably don't want to create a form just for that. You'd be better off using a link. So that would be something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', mycontroller_path(object_to_destroy), method: :delete %>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just a quick question, what would I replace my `:url  => {:action => 'destroy', :id => params[:id]}` once I add that middle line to the routes file?

Comment: If all you need is a delete button, then you probably don't want to create a form just for that. You'd be better off using a link. So that would be something like:

`<%= link_to 'Delete', mycontroller_path(object_to_destroy), method: :delete %>`

Comment: If my answer worked for you, it'd be great if you could mark it best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `destroy` action to your routes.

Add the following line: `resources :pallet_hists` to your `config/routes.rb`would solve the problem.This will add all routes (`update`, `index`, `create`...).

You can use `resources :pallet_hists, only: :destroy` if you only want to add `destroy` route.